# SQL count() in query

Tags: sql

I have table like this...

```
cola colb
  11   r
  11   r
  11   r
  21   k
  21   k
  21   m
  31   x
  31   y
  31   z
```

I want to get:

```
cola count()
11    1
21    2
31    3
```

I want to count how many distinct values in col b exists in each col a.

Thanks!

Comment: sql server or mysql ??

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming MySQL or MSSQL the following should work for you:

```
SELECT `ColA`, COUNT(DISTINCT `ColB`)
FROM `Data`
GROUP BY `ColA`
ORDER BY `ColA` ASC;
```

This gets the Distinct (unique) Count of column B for each value of Column A.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48ee7/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQL is SQL Server, try this:

```
SELECT 
   ColA, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT ColB) Cnt
FROM 
   TableName
GROUP BY 
   ColA
```

The DISTINCT clause will take care of only counting distinct entries in ColB

Comment: That's actually standard SQL and not specific to SQL Server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, I don't have a wide SQL knowledge other than specific to MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE #tab
    (
      colA INT ,
      colB VARCHAR(10)
    )
INSERT  INTO #tab
        ( colA, colB )
VALUES  ( 11, 'r' )
INSERT  INTO #tab
        ( colA, colB )
VALUES  ( 11, 'r' )
INSERT  INTO #tab
        ( colA, colB )
VALUES  ( 11, 'r' )
INSERT  INTO #tab
        ( colA, colB )
VALUES  ( 21, 'k' )
INSERT  INTO #tab
        ( colA, colB )
VALUES  ( 21, 'm' )

SELECT  t.ColA ,
        COUNT(*) AS 'count'
FROM    ( SELECT    ColA
          FROM      #tab
          GROUP BY  ColA ,
                    colB
        ) t
GROUP BY t.ColA
```